# AngularJS ng-repeat is not iterating through my JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I have build an API to get response from `MongoDB`, which is giving me response in form of `JSON` data. I have tried many solution to iterate the loop over `JSON` data with the help of ng-repeat but it didn't work for me. Here the the **HTML, JS** code of mine..and the response which i got from server.

Thankyou

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="afterLoginController" >
    <button ng-click="view()" ng-show="view_buttons"> View Attendance </button> 
    <button ng-click="fill()" ng-show="view_buttons"> Fill Attendance </button>
    <button ng-click="edit()" ng-show="view_buttons"> Edit Attendance </button>

    {{ myStudents }}
    <table>
        <th>
            <tr>Roll No</tr>
            <tr> Name </tr>
            <tr> Attendance </tr>
        </th>


                    <td ng-repeat="records in myStudents">
                        <tr>  {{ records.rollno}}       </tr>
                        <tr>  {{ records.name}}         </tr>
                        <tr>  {{ records.attendance}}   </tr>
                    </td>

        </table>


</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
app.controller("afterLoginController", function($http, $scope, $window) {

  $scope.view_buttons = true;

  $scope.view = function()
  {
    console.log('Inside view')
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_student_name")
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.view_buttons = false;
      $scope.myStudents = data;
      console.log(data);    
      alert(JSON.stringify($scope.myStudents));

    })
    .error(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    })
  };

});
```

data i.e. response from API.

```
   [
 {"division":"A","name":"Alpesh Kantilal Vasani","rollno":"01","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad970db388963024c41a18"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
{"division":"A","name":"Aesrdg Kantilal Vasani","rollno":"02","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9719b388963024c41a19"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
 {"division":"A","name":"Aesrdg Kantasdfgvbhgvilal Vasani","rollno":"03","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9721b388963024c41a1a"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
 {"division":"A","name":"Aesrdg Wrfffghy Vasani","rollno":"04","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9729b388963024c41a1b"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
 {"division":"A","name":"Aesrdg Wrfffghy Qqewfd","rollno":"05","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9732b388963024c41a1c"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
 {"division":"A","name":"Aesrdg sdfret5rgf wertyhgb","rollno":"06","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9739b388963024c41a1d"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"},
 {"division":"A","name":"Tsfgdb sdfret5rgf wertyhgb","rollno":"07","standard":"6","phone":"0000","_id":{"$oid":"59ad9743b388963024c41a1e"},"email":"alpeshvasaniav00@gmail.com"}
 ]
```

Comment: You're putting trs (table rows) inside tds (table data) of ths (table headings). That is not valid HTML. tds and ths must be inside trs. Also, success() and error() are deprecated since angular 1.4 (IIRC), and doesn't exist anymore in 1.6 (the current version). Read the $http documentation, and don't use an old version of angular.

Comment: You can try putting a tr element around your td elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above HTML you have is not valid , You should use correct syntax for the table as,

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>division</th>
          <th>name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in students">
          <td>{{x.division }}</td>
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

**EDIT:**

Also **.success()** and **`.error()`** have been depreciated with the angularjs versions above 1.4. You can read more on that **[`here`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)**

So your controller should look like,

```
pageControllers.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('students.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.students = response.data;
  });
}]);
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/YJw1mCw9Evc9cEcFRa2F?p=preview)